# ActiveAdmin: model with more than 1 new & edit form pages and collection actions for each one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activeadmin

Let's say I need different types of create/edit pages for a Post, each one optimized a different kind of Post, will show some attributes to edit them and hide others. I want 2 or 3 collection actions to choose from at the top ["create XX post", "create YY post", etc]. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use different forms for a single resource then maybe something like this:

```
action_item :new_xx_post do
  params = { post: { type: 'XX' } }
  link_to 'New XX Post', new_post_path(params)
end

controller do
  def new
    build_resource
    render resource.type == 'XX' ? 'xx_form' : 'yy_form'
  end
end
```

Rails will look for an _xx_form partial in your app/views/posts as normal. This is getting into more advanced ActiveAdmin customization so be sure you want to do this instead of just vanilla Rails.

Comment: That may do the trick. Thanks! That and also adding some condition in `permit_params` and setting the _type_ if #create fails, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You can register an ActiveRecord model multiple times [with different names](https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html#rename-the-resource), eg.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post, as: "XxPost" do ... end
ActiveAdmin.register Post, as: "YyPost" do ... end
```

Alternately use [STI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) to subclass the ActiveRecord model and register the subclasses.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I'm aware of that workaround, but I want to keep all logic inside the same ActiveAdmin registered class.